# Is it possible to have a background image for half of the page and some contents below, and hav a navmenu that remains fixed whenever I scroll down?

Tags: html, css

[image]

what I want is the top navigation block to remain fixed even when I scroll down and also have the background image to nearly top half of the page beneath the navbar(asit will be translucent and the image would be visible ) and other contents below so that it would not be on top of the  image but below the image bottom,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML looks like

```
<div id="top">
     <div id="nav">... navbar goes here ...</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
     ... other content goes here ...
</div>
```

then this CSS should do the trick:

```
#top {
     background: url(image_path);
     position: fixed; 
     top: 0;
     height: 500px; /* whatever the height of the background image is */
}

#content {
     margin-top: 500px; /* whatever you set as the height above */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set fixed navmenu in CSS

```
.nevmenu{
   position:fixed;
}
```

and for half background image. I found this link useful.
http://www.techsirius.com/2013/08/cover-half-body-background-with-image.html

They have given two methods

**Method 1:**

```
body{
background-image: url(bg_img.jpg);
background-size: 100% 50%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

**Method 2:**

Copy above CSS code in HTML header

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var h = $(window).height();
$('body').css('background-size', '100% '+(h/2)+'px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
body { background-image: url('mypic.gif'); }
#nav { position: fixed; z-index: 1000; }
```